# Accessing object attribute dynamically

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a list of objects. I want to access their attributes dynamically. 
From a drop down. But I can't manage to do so.

example:

pseudo object

```
{
 color.name = red
 color.id   = 3
}{ 
 color.name = blue
 color.id = 4
}
```

pseudo html-angular
 repeat: color
 {{color}}

if I chose from the drop down name. then the pseudo html-angular would show

-red
  -blue

I know I could copy all the attributes and hide the ones not selects, but that will make a lot of noise in the html.

Is there any way?

here is the JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/E6yZ8/

```
<div ng-app="miniapp">
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
        <select ng-model="attribute" ng-change="setAttribute(attribute)">
            <option value="name">name</option>
            <option value="shade">shade</option>
            <option value="id">id</option>
        </select>
        <br/>
        <div ng-repeat='color in colors'>
            {{color}}
        </div>
        <br>
            Desire attribute = {{desireAttribute}}
    </div>                           
</div>


  var $scope;
  var app = angular.module('miniapp', []);

  function Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.attributes = ['name','shade','id'];
    $scope.colors = [
        {name:'Red', shade: 'white',id:1}, 
        {name:'Orange', shade: 'red',id:2}, 
        {name:'Yellow', shade: 'blue',id:3}, 
        {name:'Green', shade: 'yellow',id:4}, 
        {name:'Blue', shade: 'indigo',id:5}, 
        {name:'Indigo', shade: 'violet',id:6}, 
        {name:'Violet', shade: 'orange',id:7}
    ];

    $scope.desireAttribute = 'none';
    $scope.setAttribute= function(attribute){
    $scope.desireAttribute = attribute;
  }; 
};
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanna show only selected attribute:

```
{{color[attribute]}}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E6yZ8/1/)

Btw, you can improve your `<select>` by using `ng-options` directive (more Angular way :) )

```
<select ng-model="attribute" ng-options="option for option in attributes">
</select>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E6yZ8/2/)

Comment: Awesome!
Thank you very much! Thats what I wanted!